# Expand parent prefix number to a given child number

Tags: python

I have a parent prefix number and a child number that begins with the same prefix. I want to expand the parent number up to the target child number
in a way that all prefixes be included and show the target, for example.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                                                         +
+ Example #1              +  Example #2               +  Example #3                +
+ parent=123, target=1235 +  parent=123, target=12354 +  parent=123, target=123073 +
+                         +                           +                            +
+ Expansion would be:     +  Expansion would be:      +  Expansion would be:       +
+                         +                           +                            +
+ 123-0                   +  123-0                    +  123-0-0                   +
+ 123-1                   +  123-1                    +  123-0-1                   +
+ 123-2                   +  123-2                    +  123-0-2                   +
+ 123-4                   +  123-4                    +  123-0-3                   +
+ 123-5  --> target       +  123-5-0                  +  123-0-4                   +
+ 123-6                   +  123-5-1                  +  123-0-5                   +
+ 123-7                   +  123-5-2                  +  123-0-6                   +
+ 123-8                   +  123-5-4  --> target      +  123-0-7-0                 +
+ 123-9                   +  123-5-5                  +  123-0-7-1                 +
+                         +  123-5-6                  +  123-0-7-2                 +
+                         +  123-5-7                  +  123-0-7-3 --> target      +
+                         +  123-5-8                  +  123-0-7-4                 +
+                         +  123-5-9                  +  123-0-7-5                 +
+                         +  123-6                    +  123-0-7-6                 +
+                         +  123-7                    +  123-0-7-7                 +
+                         +  123-8                    +  123-0-7-8                 +
+                         +  123-9                    +  123-0-7-9                 +
+                         +                           +  123-0-8                   +
+                         +                           +  123-0-9                   +
+                         +                           +  123-1                     +
+                         +                           +  123-2                     +
+                         +                           +  123-3                     +
+                         +                           +  123-4                     +
+                         +                           +  123-5                     +
+                         +                           +  123-6                     +
+                         +                           +  123-7                     +
+                         +                           +  123-8                     +
+                         +                           +  123-9                     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Like you see,

- In example #1, target is 4 digit length and only one level expansion
  was needed
- In example #2, target is 5 digit length and two level
  expansion was needed
- In example #3, target is 6 digit length and    three level expansion
  was needed

In my current code shown below, I'm only able to print one level expansion and only for one target. I'm stuck in how to expand the parent number when target length is greater in 2 or more digits compared with length of parent and if input targets are more than one. Help would be appreciated.

```
parent="1312314"
child="13123147674"

l = len(parent)
target=child[l:]

t=int(target[0])

for k in range(t):
    print(parent + str(k))

print(parent + str(t) + " --> target")

for k in range(t+1,10):
    print(parent + str(k))
```

Current output:

```
13123140
13123141
13123142
13123143
13123144
13123145
13123146
13123147 --> target
13123148
13123149
```

**Update**

```
Example #4
parent=12345, target1=1234538, target2=1234570924, target3=123459

Expansion would be:

123450
123451
123452
1234530
1234531
1234532
1234533
1234534
1234535
1234536
1234537
1234538 --> target
1234539
123454
123455
123456
12345700
12345701
12345702
12345703
12345704
12345705
12345706
12345707
12345708
123457090
123457091
1234570920
1234570921
1234570922
1234570923
1234570924 --> target
1234570925
1234570926
1234570927
1234570928
1234570929
123457093
123457094
123457095
123457096
123457097
123457098
123457099
1234571
1234572
1234573
1234574
1234575
1234576
1234577
1234578
1234579
123458
123459 --> target
```

Comment: Because you are taking only 1 element in target[0]. So it will be 7. you need to loop target[i] if you want other elements too

Comment: In that part of how to loop target[I] is where I'm stuck in how to make it work.

Comment: If you want to make this infinite (eg. the second number way longer than the first) then I think this calls for a recursive function. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this. the trick is `result.sort()`

```
parent="123"
child= "12354"

p = len(parent)
c = len(child)
result = []

for i in range(p, c):
    for x in range(0, 10):
        y = child[0:i] + str(x)
        result.append(y)    

result.sort()

for a in result:
    print (a + ("--> target" if a == child else ""))
```

Result:

```
1230
1231
1232
1233
1234
1235
12350
12351
12352
12353
12354--> target
12355
12356
12357
12358
12359
1236
1237
1238
1239
```

for multiple targets:

```
parent="12345"
target1="1234538"
target2="1234570924"
target3="123459"

targets = [target1, target2, target3]
result = []

for target in targets:
    for i in range(len(parent), len(target)):
        for x in range(0, 10):
            y = target[0:i] + str(x)
            result.append(y)    

result = list(set(result))
result.sort()

for a in result:
    print (a + ("--> target" if a in targets else ""))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works excellent and is even a more compact solution. May you help me if you have a chance for the second question in my original post, that is handle the case when targets are more than one like in example#4. Thanks again

Comment: you can wrap it with the list of targets. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

u can do as below:

```
parent='123' 
child='123073'

if len(child)> len(parent):
    tuple_list =[]

    nums_to_append=child[len(parent):]
    l = len(nums_to_append)

    for i,num in enumerate(nums_to_append):
        for j in range(10):
            if num == str(j):
                tuple_list.append((parent,j+1))
                parent = parent+num
                if i==(l-1):
                    print(parent, "--> target")

                break
            else:
                print(parent+str(j))

    for parent,num in tuple_list[::-1]:
        for j in range(num,10):
            print(parent+str(j))
```

```
12300
12301
12302
12303
12304
12305
12306
123070
123071
123072
123073 --> target
123074
123075
123076
123077
123078
123079
12308
12309
1231
1232
1233
1234
1235
1236
1237
1238
1239
```

Comment: This works only if the second number is 2 chars longer than the first one

Comment: @Shijith Hello. Thanks for your help. I've been trying and it seems to work pretty fine. I was wondering if you could help in how to make it work when there are more than one target (1 to n targets). I've updated my original post with example #4, where there are 3 targets and the corresponding output.